# angular bootstrap modal - close only after savesuccess

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using the [angular bootstrap modal control](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) to edit and save some data. When I click on the save button it immediately closes, because of the following:

```js
 $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };
```

```js
  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
```

what I want is to perform my save operation within the ok() and after it succeed only close the modal. If there are any errors, the modal should not close.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this....

```
   $scope.ok = function () {
    $http.post('/UrSaveUrl', {msg:'hello word!'}).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

      });
      };
```